# Difference between IUnityContainer.RegisterType() and UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType()?

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism-6

I am running a WPF Application using Prism and Unity for DI. I have a Shell: MainWindow.xaml, A Container: AppContainer.xaml, and the startup view: StartupView.xaml.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="App.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
...
...
...
>

    <Grid Background="Transparent">

        <ContentControl x:Name="ContainerRegion"
                               prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContainerRegion"/>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

AppContainer.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="App.Views.AppContainer"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
...
...
...
>

    <Grid>
        <ContentControl x:Name="MainViewRegion"
                               prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainViewRegion" />



    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

The StartupView.xaml code is not relevant.

I instantiate the shell in the bootstrapper. I added an AppContainerModule. Here is the initialize():

```
public override void Initialize()
        {

            UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType(_unityContainer, typeof(Object), typeof(AppContainer), InstanceNames.AppContainer); //InstanceNames is a static class of "magic" strings

            IRegion mviewRegion = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.ContainerRegion]; //ContainerRegion is the Region declared in MainWindow.xaml

            if (mviewRegion == null) return;


            _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ContainerRegion, new Uri(InstanceNames.AppContainer, UriKind.Relative));

    }
```

Here is my StartupViewModule.Initialize()

```
public override void Initialize()
        {

            UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType(_unityContainer, typeof(object), typeof(StartupView), InstanceNames.StartupView);



            IRegion mviewRegion = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainViewRegion]; //MainViewRegion is declared in AppContainer.xaml

            if (mviewRegion == null) return;


            _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainViewRegion, new Uri(InstanceNames.StartupView, UriKind.Relative));

        }
```

In a small diagram:

```
MainWindow.xaml -> [ContainerRegion]
                           |
                           |
                           \/
                    AppContainer.xaml -> [MainViewRegion]
                                                |
                                                |
                                                \/
                                          StartupView.xaml
```

I used the [ModuleDependency] Attributes to ensure that StartupView is Initialized after AppContainer.

The above code works, btw!

My question is regarding the prior code I had before stumbling upon this solution. I was getting a crash upon launch with the error that prism could not find the MainViewRegion when StartupView was trying to inject itself (during StartupViewModule.Initialize() ). Changing the code to the above worked. What didn't work was the following in **AppContainerModule**

```
_unityContainer.RegisterType<AppContainer>(InstanceNames.AppContainer);
```

Again, what did work was this:

```
UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType(_unityContainer, typeof(Object), typeof(AppContainer), InstanceNames.AppContainer);
```

So my question is, why?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.unitycontainerextensions.registertype(v=pandp.51).aspx) it would seem as though in the one that is working you are telling the container the from and to type, but in the one that isn't working, you are only providing the to type. I would guess that `_unityContainer.RegisterType<Object, AppContainer>(InstanceNames.AppContainer);` would also work.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment Thanks! That actually works. So it's the From -> To snip that was the problem. Now I just need to refresh my memory on why the From parameter is important :p

Comment: `IUnityContainer.RegisterType` is implemented via the `UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType` method so they are functionally equivalent.  You could also do something like `_unityContainer.RegisterType(typeof(Object), typeof(AppContainer), InstanceNames.AppContainer);`